# what does the phrase “ on the same spectrum “ mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the sentence : My disease is nowhere near as bad as hers but they are on the same spectrum

Comment: I suggest you google: spectrum of disease.

Comment: You don't even have to do that. [Spectrum](https://www.lexico.com/definition/spectrum): "Used to classify something in terms of its position on a scale between two extreme points." -- so, the diseases are on the same scale, of the same type.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, the question is not quite as naïve as it may, at first, appear to be, because the use of the word in this context is different from its use in other contexts, in fact, so different that it may be confusing to those who rely on the definitions, such as the one you quote, that reflect its ordinary use. When the word is used in this context, one can usually see what one of the extreme points is, but it typically less than clear what the other one is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that both the maladies are akin to each other. Not much discrepancies between the two.